# Python - why won't while loop end program?

Tags: python, while-loop

So this is a little game I have made but when either user_lives or comp_lives equals 0 it does not end the loop and I don't understand why.

It works if I set the while loop to: while user_lives > 1 or comp_lives > 1:

I can also fix it by putting a break in the if statements of both the elif statements but then I should just be able to set while to True and use an infinite loop. This works but I would like to know why this while loop doesn't work.

Any help would be great!

```
from random import randint

user_lives = 3
comp_lives = 3

print("Welcome to the number guessing game!!!")
print("The game will choose a number between 0 and 10 and you must guess right before the computer does!!!")

while user_lives > 0 or comp_lives > 0:
    random_num = randint(0, 10)
    user_num = raw_input("Choose a number between 0 and 10: ")
    comp_num = randint(0, 10)
    print(random_num)
    print(comp_num)

    if int(user_num) == random_num and comp_num == random_num:
        print("Its a draw.")

    elif comp_num == random_num:
        print ("The computer has WON!")
        user_lives = user_lives - 1
        print("You have " + str(user_lives) + " lives left.")
        if user_lives == 0:
            print("GAME OVER.")         

    elif int(user_num) == random_num:
        print("You have WON!")
        comp_lives = comp_lives - 1
        print("The computer has " + str(comp_lives) + " lives left.")
        if comp_lives == 0:
            print("GAME OVER.")

    else:
        print("No one wins. Try again.")
```

Comment: because its an OR instead of AND?

Comment: Looks like your loop won't end until *both* players die!  :-)

Comment: Have you checked out Vincent's solution? It is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes it makes sense now, cheers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have posted has the logic as follows:

IF `user_lives` > 0, continue the loop. OR
IF `comp_lives` > 0, continue the loop.

Do you see the problem? The loop can ONLY end if BOTH `user` and `comp` lives `<=0`.

I think perhaps a better loop would be

`while user_lives > 0 and comp_lives > 0:`

Comment: Don't you mean `while ...` instead of `if ...` ?